# Java NullPointerException With Character Array

Tags: java

Hello I'm trying to make a simple game engine and I need to access two 2 - dimensional character arrays from another class Here is my code from the class that the arrays are declared in:

`protected char[][] idMap;
protected char[][] hardMap;`

Then later on after I declaire these I give them a value based on use input:

```
    public void createWindow(int width, int height, int tileScale,
        String title) {
    char[][] newMap = new char[height][width]; // y x
    idMap = newMap;
    hardMap = newMap;
```

Then I try to change a value in one of the arrays in a different class and I get an error:

```
GameWindow window;
```

window.idMap[5][5] = 'a';

The Error is "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Can someone please help me and explain what I'm doing wrong, and thank you in advance! :D

Comment: Is `getScale` a variable of the class, or a method? What error is it giving you?

Comment: Please include details about what the "Auto-Unboxing Issue" is.  Please include any relevant compiler error messages, exception stack traces, or incorrect output.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: You don't need to cast `null` here.

Comment: if `getScale` is an `int` or `Integer` then there is a possible loss of precision at `oLocationX += x / getScale`. Not autoboxing but is that what your talking about?

Comment: `char`s cannot be null, since they are not objects. Use the null character `'\0' = 0`.

Comment: Thanks I think it worked, I'll test with the console

Comment: Actually I'm still getting an error with it, would it be landscape.map[oLocationY / getScale][oLocationX / getScale] = '\0';

Comment: You have to give us the entirety of the error message. Many things could be wrong, and without the error we do not know what is causing the problem. For all we know, "//This is the Problem:" could be incorrect.

Comment: Okay I am still having the same problem, but it is actually a java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize correctly the two dimensional array:

Try this

```
int width=10;
int height = 10;
char[][] idMap = new char[width][];
for(int i =0 :i< width:i++){
   idMap[i] = new char[height];
}
idMap[5][5] = 'a';
```

Comment: The thing about this is: idMap[5][5] = 'a'; would work in the class I declared it in :/

Comment: I don't understand, please be more clear " would work in the class I declared it in"?. (I have made a few changes in my answer try it)